# Passing different Objects from XmlSerializer function

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How can we pass different Object from a given function.

```
 static public void SerializeToXML(FbTextView p)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FbTextView));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\movie.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, p);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
```

now the problem is that when I try to pass two or more then two objects like this:

```
  static public void SerializeToXML(FbTextView p,FbTextField q)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FbTextView));
        XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FbTextField));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\movie.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, p);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
```

it throw error: XMLParse Exception Was unhandled. and the inner exception is : 
"There was an error reflecting type 'FBformBuilder.FbTextField"
thanks !

Comment: btw; it is much better to us a `using` statement around things like `TextWriter`, so that the file gets closed even if there is an exception

Comment: something wrong in `FbTextField` class. Please show the code for it

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly: here is 
 //   [XmlRoot("TextFieldObject")]
    public class FbTextField : FbBaseControl
    {
      [XmlElement(Type=typeof(FbTextField))]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @HmXa indeed, so I ran that and looked at the inner exceptions, as per my answer: "There was an error reflecting type 'FbTextField'.", "There was an error reflecting property 'Value'.", "The type for XmlElement may not be specified for primitive types.". It **tells you** what you need to do: take the `Type=` out of that `[XmlElement(...)]` against `.Value`. Working class definition: `[XmlRoot("TextFieldObject")] public class FbTextField : FbBaseControl { public string Value { get; set; } }` (note I removed the `[XmlElement(...)]` *completely* because that is the default anyway)

Comment: @MarcGravell: i Remove this. but the result of XML is :
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: file:///D:/movie.xml
Line Number 6, Column 14:</FbTextView><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
-------------^
and sorry for very late reply :)

Comment: @HmXa did you write two objects as xml to the same writer? that isn't valid. It looks like there's an xml-header after the `FbTextView` - but an xml document can only have one root, and only one header, and the header *must* be right at the start of the file. If you need to do that, create a type that *has* an instance of the two things, and serialize *that*, so you get `<SomeWrapper><FirstThing ... /><SecondThing ... /></SomeWrapper>`

Comment: @MarcGravell : can you elaborate more. because i am new in C#. kindly give me a code example. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be fully detailed in the inner exceptions; try:

```
try {
    // ... your code
} catch(Exception ex) {
    while(ex != null) {
        Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }
    throw;
}
```

then look at all the `.Message`s that get logged. One of these will tell you the exact problem. For example, it could be something like:

- no public parameterless constructor
- not a public type
- invalid sub-class
- duplicated/ambiguous element/namespace

or something similar

Comment: the inner exception is: "there was an error reflecting property value".

Comment: and another : the type for XMlElement may not be specified for premitive types

Comment: @HmXa exactly. So: *don't specify the type in the `[XmlElement(...)]` for a `string`*

Answer (score 0):

inner exception:

> The type for XmlElement may not be specified for primitive types.

Remove `[XmlElement(Type)]` attribute from `FbTextField` `Value` field

Comment: after removing the result XML file output is: 

XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: file:///D:/movie.xml
Line Number 6, Column 14:</FbTextView><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
-------------^